# How can I see how many values in an array are unique. As in do not equal other values in the array forward or backward?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to see how many unique values are in an array. Unique being it does not equal any other strings in the array forward or backward. Here is what I have, But it does return the right values every time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Answer {   
    public static int answer(String[] x) { 
        ArrayList<String> collectionOfCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        int arrayLength = x.length;

        for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++) {
            if(collectionOfCodes.contains(x[index]) || collectionOfCodes.contains(x[index])) {} 
            else {
                collectionOfCodes.add(x[index]);
            }
        }
        return collectionOfCodes.size();
     }
}
```

**NOTE:** Clarification for other readers of this question, from OP's comments to answers:

The phrase "forward or backward" does *not* mean earlier or later in the array, but instead refers to the string being read left-to-right and right-to-left, e.g. `abcde` and `edcba` are considered the "same" value.

Answer (score 3):

Your code above is wrong, you're not checking for reverse, but you're checking twice for the same thing:

`if(collectionOfCodes.contains(x[index]) || collectionOfCodes.contains(x[index])) {}`

Anyways, you could create a loop and add each string in a cannonical form to a HashSet. The cannonical form could be to always use the one that comes before in a lexical comparison:

```
HashSet hashset = new HashSet();
for(String str : x) {
  String reverse = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
  hashset.add(str.compareTo(reverse) <= 0 ? str : reverse);
}
return hashset.size();
```